# Can't set cookie with Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, backend

can't set cookie from my ayth controller, can't understand why.
If i set from folder app.js everything fine.

```
const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    secure: false,
  };
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true;
  user.password = undefined;

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used cookie-parser ?
Because As of now the cookie parser is a separate npm package, so instead of using

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Comment: Yes i use it in app.js

Answer (score -1):

That resolve my problem

```js
const cookieOptions = {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
};
```

Comment: explain the reason why it resolved your problem.